# rpmbuild skip "checking for unpackaged file(s) /usr/lib/rpm/check-files"

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

While building kernel rpm package`rpmbuild` does it's slow "Checking for unpackaged file(s)" check:

```
$ make -j$(nproc) binrpm-pkg
...
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /home/user/rpmbuild/BUI
LDROOT/kernel-4.17.0_rc5_next_20180517_3.gd86d9e8_default+-98.x86_64
```

For kernel even on powerful machine it takes 30 mins. How to avoid that?
I've tried to to avoid it with `_unpackaged_files_terminate_build`, but it didn't help:

```
echo "%_unpackaged_files_terminate_build    0" >> ~/.rpmmacros
```

Also adding `--nocheck` to `rpmbuild` call to `binrpm-pkg` target in `scripts/package/Makefile` didn't help.

But maybe it's something else wrong. When I build with configuration `make allyesconfig` rpm file has 168MB. RPM file builded with openSUSE Tumbleweed config has 647MB.

Answer (score 4):

Got same issue and found out what was happening.

If your `rpmbuild` is slow to process it doesn't come from `/usr/lib/rpm/check-files` script:
try to comment all its lines, you'll see that it's still hanging after that, even if this script is basically doing nothing anymore.

Executing :

```
strace -f -s900 rpmbuild [your args]
```

You'll see that between hangs, DNS calls are issued (calls to `/usr/lib64/libresolv.so` library) trying to resolve the hostname of your build machine, which fall on timeout after some time and then retries .

If your machine have a faulty DNS configuration or if your DNS server is not working, the `rpmbuild` process will hang on each launch.

**To avoid those hangs:**

- correct your DNS configuration on your build machine, or
- `sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf` on your build machine

The real question remaining is: *Why a local process like rpmbuild is doing DNS calls?*

Comment: I poked at the source code and added it to an answer below. TLDR: _buildhost is being set by RPM and for some reason it's deciding to canonicalize the hostname of the local machine. If you override it with a --define it skips the check. Useful for when you have 10s of RPMs.

Comment: I'm not really sure if `sudo rm -f /etc/resolv.conf` is a good suggestion. (Maybe NetworkManager will survive this, but how about Wicked used in openSUSE?)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, I'm pretty sure you cannot stop it. Is it on a slow drive? Are you in an enterprise environment where `/home/user` is network-mounted?

What you tried to change simply says "if you find files that I didn't account for, make it a *warning* not an *error*."

Comment: I think the problem is in some config: when I build with configuration make allyesconfig rpm file has 168MB. RPM file builded with openSUSE Tumbleweed's config has 647MB and takes so long. No idea how to find "problematic" option.

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, the problem line is in [`buildHost(void)`](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/rpm/blob/5f98b1aa4817d5923caef42208e32eb34094e94b/build/build.c#L47C20-L47C20) inside build RPM.

Code:

```c
    bhMacro = rpmExpand("%{?_buildhost}", NULL);
    if (strcmp(bhMacro, "") != 0) {
        rasprintf(&hostname, "%s", bhMacro);
    } else {
    hostname = rcalloc(NI_MAXHOST + 1, sizeof(*hostname));
    if (gethostname(hostname, NI_MAXHOST) == 0) {
        struct addrinfo *ai, hints;
        memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
        hints.ai_flags = AI_CANONNAME;

        if (getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &ai) == 0) {
        strcpy(hostname, ai->ai_canonname);
        freeaddrinfo(ai);
        } else {
        rpmlog(RPMLOG_WARNING,
                    _("Could not canonicalize hostname: %s\n"), hostname);
        }
    }
```

If you define `_buildhost` with hostname, it will skip the DNS call.

Example:

```bash
rpmbuild -bb --define "_buildhost $(hostname)" ./path/to/spec/file.spec
```

Note: the install will still hang on the "check files" part, but it's doing other stuff in the background, and the DNS call itself will be skipped.